# Default checkbox with checked not working

Tags: android, android-checkbox

`CheckBox` default value is not working. I have given the `CheckBox` value by `setcheck(true)` and also given in layout and i need to pass the checked value to arraylist.

How to use arraylist to send values between two classes how to save data in asset `db` in android.

```
  public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
  {

   RetrieveFromDB sqlConn;
    private final Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> resArray;
    public static ArrayList<String> selitemsList=new ArrayList<String>();

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> resArray)
    {
    super(context, R.layout.categorylist, resArray);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.resArray = resArray;
     }
     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup       parent) {

    try{
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_2, parent, false);
        CheckBox chk=(CheckBox)rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        TextView  list= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        list.setText(resArray.get(position).toString());
        sqlConn=new RetrieveFromDB(context);
          selitemsList=sqlConn.displaySelectedItems(EditSelectedItems.sel_category);
        sqlConn.close();

        if(selitemsList.contains(list.getText().toString()))
            chk.setChecked(true);
        else
            chk.setChecked(false);
        chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(isChecked)
                {
                             CategoryListView.st.add(resArray.get(position).toString());
                    selitemsList.add(resArray.get(position).toString());

                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code about .setChecked is right. Try to log something about selitemsList content, and you can check logcat. For example

```
Log.d("my debug", "selitemsList content:");
for (String s: selitemsList){
    Log.d("my debug", "\t- " + s);
}
if(selitemsList.contains(list.getText().toString())){
    Log.d("my debug", "selitemsList contains " + list.getText().toString());
    chk.setChecked(true);
}else{
    Log.d("my debug", "selitemsList doesn't contain " + list.getText().toString());
    chk.setChecked(false);
}
```

In this mode you should be able to see in logcat where is the problem. Maybe selitemsList is not correctly filled.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SparseBooleanArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html) to get list of selected items.

```
int len = listView.getCount();
ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (checked.get(i)) {
    String item = cont_list.get(i);
    selectedItems.add(item);
}
```